# Rewriting URLs and "faking" folders

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying use mod_rewrite to rewrite URLs from the following:

```
http://www.site.com/one-two-file.php
```

to

```
http://www.site.com/one/two/file.php
```

The folders don't exist, but "virtually" exist for the rewriting purpose.

What rule do I used in this?

Comment: Where would the folder names come from?

Comment: Ideally, the "faked" folders would come from the URL, but would never exist on the server.

Comment: I'd update your example to make that clear. E.g., you want the public URL to be `http://www.site.com/one/two/file.php` when the unrewritten version would be `http://www.site.com/one-two-file.php`.

Comment: There are no folders in a URL. They are called path segments and reflect the hierarchy of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.php$ $1-$2-$3.php [L]
```

I can't really understand your explanations about virtuality and existence: one-two-file.php must exist or you'll have nowhere to redirect to.

### Update

The previous version works fine when used from an `.htaccess` file. However, if used from main http.conf file you need to add leading slashes:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.php$ /$1-$2-$3.php [L]
```

I presume that's why it wasn't working for the OP (he was probably getting a 404 not found status code).

Comment: They are called "path segments" - so one/two/file.html goes to one-two-file.php :)

Comment: Does it not work in any special way? How are you testing exactly? Is mod_rewrite loaded and enabled?

Comment: Hi, was adding it directly to httpd.conf.

Thanks :)